# how to store notifications from firebase to android app using shared preferences

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, sharedpreferences

I want to store notifications received from `Firebase` in my android app. I am using `SharedPreferences` for that. The problem is when I send notification more then 1 time it overwrites the previous one.

```
String[] notif={"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""};
ListAdapter yo = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,notif);
ListView yup = findViewById(R.id.list1);
yup.setAdapter(yo);

SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("notification", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String y = sharedPref.getString("notify","");
notif[1]=y;
```

Comment: Does the notification gets overwritten or the values in SharedPreferences?

Comment: The values in the shared preference

Answer (score 0):

just create another class AppCache. In which you have to do all sharedPreference related work like storing/retrieving the data from/into sharedPreference. Here is the class

```
public class AppCache {

    private static final String PREF = "notificationApp";
    private static final String COUNT_KEY = "count_key";


    public static void saveNotification(Context context, String notification) {

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int count = sharedPref.getInt(COUNT_KEY , 0);
    count++;
        sharedPref.edit().putString("notification"+count, notification).apply();
    //saving count in prefs
    sharedPref.edit().putInt(COUNT_KEY , count).apply();
    }


}
```

1 -> In SharedPreferences create another integer for count that will hold the number of notifications in sharedPreferences.

2 -> While saving the notification in sharedpreference, use a unique key for every notification,for example you can use a combination of any string and the count which you declared before like "notification"+(count++). count++ will create a new key for every new notification.

3 -> Now you can retrieve all notification by using count.

Comment: this is my code for saving data in sharedpreference, kindly tell me how can i introduce a count here        
        
        
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("notification",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putString("notify",x);
        editor.apply();

Comment: have a look at updated answer

Comment: Thanks a lot sir

Comment: welcome vikas, plz do up vote if this answer is helpful